# Android Bitmap compress from gallery cause OutOfMemoryError in Xiomi phones

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-imageview

The below code gives **OutOfMemoryError** while compress method is executed in Xiomi, ASUS Zenfone2 and Samsung S5 devices alone.

```
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(<sd_card_path_here>);
  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, out);
```

**Destination sd card path has a file created with 0 bytes**

Any help is highly appreciated and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I m using Xiaomi mi3 and i have tried this, there is no `outOfMemoryError`. Would you like to tell what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should read loading bitmap efficiently to give you the basic understanding of why you might be experiencing OutOfMemory exception. 
Additionally, processing Bitmap should be done off the UI thread to avoid ANR error as well.

Ref: 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

what width/height does the bitmap have?

Android's OpenGL version has a limit of 4096*4096 pixel (65 Megabyte uncompressed image) per Bitmap

You can also try to increase apps memory in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application ...
    android:largeHeap="true"..></application>
```

If this does not help you have to scale down the image as described in  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I got working answer from here :

```
    public String compressImage(String imageUri) {
 
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
 
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 
//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
 
        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
 
//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612
 
        float maxHeight = 816.0f;
        float maxWidth = 612.0f;
        float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;
 
//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image
 
        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {               imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);               actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;             } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
 
            }
        }
 
//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image
 
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
 
//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
 
//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
 
        try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
 
        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;
 
        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);
 
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));
 
//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
 
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
 
//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
            scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        return filename;
 
    }


public String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    return uriSting;
 
}


private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
 
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height/ (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;      }       final float totalPixels = width * height;       final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;       while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }
 
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

reference link :  [LINK](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/)